# OneSignal in Xamarin.iOS - No notification sound when screen is locked

Tags: ios, push-notification, xamarin.ios, onesignal

I'm using the OneSignal framework to handle push in my Xamarin.iOS app. When the app is active, or even just when the screen is lit up and unlocked, the notifications appear, with vibration and their custom sound. However when I lock my screen the notifications arrive silently, meaning there is no vibration or sound, and the screen doesn't light up.

I really haven't tried that much since I don't know what to try. I've followed this guide, from OneSignal's documentation: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/xamarin-sdk-setup

In the AppDelegate I simply initialize OneSignal like so:

```
OneSignal.Current.StartInit("[MyAppID]").EndInit();
```

And then in the NotificationService (in the NotificationServiceExtension), in the method `DidReceiveNotificationRequest`, I do:

```
public override void DidReceiveNotificationRequest(UNNotificationRequest request, Action<UNNotificationContent> contentHandler)
{
    ReceivedRequest = request;
    ContentHandler = contentHandler;
    BestAttemptContent = (UNMutableNotificationContent)request.Content.MutableCopy();

    (OneSignal.Current as OneSignalImplementation).DidReceiveNotificationExtensionRequest(request, BestAttemptContent);

    ContentHandler(BestAttemptContent);
}
```

I expect "locked-screen-notification" to behave like they do when the screen is unlocked, but instead they are always silent. And I have not used any silent-flags.

Comment: Is you phone in a silent mode or enabled the Do-not-disturbed mode?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Sadly no, I get sound from other notifications.